# What happened to Helicarrier no. 64 following the events of Avengers: Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron, agents-of-shield

In *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, Coulson enacts Theta Protocol and sends Helicarrier no. 64 to help the Avengers.

[image: Helicarrier no. 64 image 1]

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, we see the helicarrier arrive in Sokovia and carry out the evacuation of the city.

[image: Helicarrier no. 64 image 2]

So far, this helicarrier has not been seen again, in either the films or television series.

Do we know its current location and owner?

Comment: Sadly, after the damage it suffered rescuing all those Sovokians, [it got sold for scrap](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Deadpool-Really-Did-Have-Major-Connection-Marvel-Avengers-Here-How-113067.html).

Comment: lol at the Deadpool link. In any case, most likely it's simply off-screen.

Answer (score 1):

After the damage, Agent Coulson took it to the Theta Protocol Facility and began to repair it in case there will be an emergency.

Reference: *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D* Season 2.

Comment: Which episode in particular? You may be confused. Age of Ultron is after S2E12.

Comment: Whilst a nice answer could you reference specific episodes or even scenes and add in some quotes or video links showing this as evidence?